# Theanets: Removing individual connections

Tags: neural-network, connectivity, theano

How do you remove connections in Theanets? I'd like to create custom connectivity between an input layer, a single hidden layer, and an output layer. But the only defaults are feedforward all-to-all architectures or recurrent architectures. I'd like to remove specific connections from the all-to-all connectivity and then train the network.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

(Developer of `theanets` here.)

This is currently not directly possible with [theanets](http://theanets.readthedocs.org). For computational efficiency the underlying computations in feedforward networks are implemented as simple matrix operations, which are fast and can be executed on a GPU for sometimes dramatic speedups.

You can, however, *initialize* the weights in a layer so that some (or many) of the weights are zero. To do this, just pass a dictionary in the `layers` list, and include a `sparsity` key:

```
import theanets

net = theanets.Autoencoder(
    layers=(784, dict(size=1000, sparsity=0.9), 784))
```

This initializes the weights for the layer so that the given fraction of weights are zeros. The weights are, however, eligible for change during the training process, so this is only an initialization trick.

You can, however, implement a custom [`Layer`](http://theanets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/theanets.layers.Layer.html) subclass that does whatever you like, as long as you stay within the [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano) boundaries. You could, for instance, implement a type of feedforward layer that uses a mask to ensure that some weights remain zeros during the feedforward computation.

For more details you might want to ask on the [theanets mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/theanets).

Comment: Quick Question, Lief, is it possible to emulate a feed-forward network with custom connections by specifying it as an RNN and setting the hh matrix parameter such that there are no hidden-hidden connections and specifying the xh matrix parameter to provide just the connections desired? (maybe I misunderstand the nature of these matrices.)

Comment: It's possible to do that, but it's totally unnecessary to introduce the hh matrix and then zero it out. Also would be slow because recurrent layers use scan. Try writing the group for details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/theanets